# spark read file not include pattern

Tags: python, bash, apache-spark, hadoop

```
df = sc.textFile("hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/*/part-*.gz")
```

I use this code to read gz files all in the path

```
    hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/
```

There are 24 files in this path from 00-23. How to read files but
exclude the 23 file?

```
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:07 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/00
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:11 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/01
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:17 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/02
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:23 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/03
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:13 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/04
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/05
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/06
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/07
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:18 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/08
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:21 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/09
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:18 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/10
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/11
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/12
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/13
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/14
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:17 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/15
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:20 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/16
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:18 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/17
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:21 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/18
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/19
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:17 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/20
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:19 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/21
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:15 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/22
drwxr-xr-x   - algo algo          0 2018-08-29 23:21 hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of workaround but hope works for you.

```
import os
file_list = os.popen('hadoop fs -ls hdfs://n21-01-03/algo/ml_platform/downsample_data/nl/20180828/').readlines()
file_list = [x for x in file_list if (x not in ['23'])]
rdd = sc.textFile(file_list.mkString(","))
```

Comment: textFile does not support passing in a list.

Comment: Sorry about that. How about `sc.textFile(file_list.mkString(","))`

Comment: That's great! =D I could use some points if you don't mind marking as answer please. Thanks so much